# ,differential equation for the 2nd order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to know which differential equation I have to solve in order to get the answer to a unitary step like the one report in figure: 
[image: I want that this curve will be obtained to a solution of my system of ode (2nd order ODE)]

tell me if I'm wrong:
starting from :

$m\frac{d^2y_1}{dt}+b\frac{dy_1}{dt}+k y_1= 0$

I can compute the substitution $\frac{dy}{dt} = y_2 $

so the system of first order equation became :
 \begin{cases} 
y'_1 = y_2 \\ 
y'_2 = -\frac{b}{m}y_2 -\frac{k}{m} \\ 
\end{cases}
right ?
how can I set the constant ? which initial value should I use ?

**EDIT**
Maybe I'm not well explain! I don't wanna know the output but which value and boundary condition I have to use in the system that I wrote in order to get the set of response in function of the parameter $\zeta$ (and also know what is $\zeta$) I know the soultion but I wanna solve the differential equations and get this set of curve !! Consider my question like: which is the function to integrate .... with wich value or like :"I have to give an exercise: using a euler method find the solution of a unit step response for different value of $\zeta$ and $\omega_o$ "

Thanks for your precious support ... what is $x(t)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you can read of a period of about $6$ which confirms the label of a frequency $ω_0=1$. Thus the basis is a harmonic oscillator $y''+(y-1)=0$. In addition there is a friction term that leads to the represented exponential decay, where one can guess that the friction coefficient is $2\zeta$ (as per the normalized form in the answer of Mostafa Ayaz). In total this makes an equation
$$y''+2\zeta y'+y=x.$$ 
As per usual in such situations of exploring system responses it is assumed that all functions are zero for $t<0$, so that the initial conditions are $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$. The unit step function is $x(t)=1$ for $t\ge 0$, and of course $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$. Then solve 
$$y''+2\zeta y'+y=1$$ 
for $t\ge 0$.

```
t = np.linspace(0,30,1501)
for zeta in [0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,4]:
    sol = odeint(lambda y,t:[y[1], 1-y[0]-2*zeta*y[1]],[0,0], t)
    plt.plot(t,sol[:,0], label="$\zeta=$%.2f"%zeta);
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output has such a Laplace transform$$Y(s)=\dfrac{1}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_0s+\omega_0^2}$$which is the output of the following ODE$$y''(t)+2\zeta\omega_0y'(t)+\omega_0^2y(t)=x(t)$$with initial rest

Comment: Thank you it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation you propose, when disturbed, will oscillate around y=0.  The differential equation you should consider is $$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+b\frac{dy}{dt}+ky=F(t)$$ where F(t) is a simple step function, namely, F=0 for t<0 and F=1/k for t>0.  This will make the displacement oscillate around 1 as above.  The solution to this equation can be achieved by several standard methods such as the Laplace transform listed @Mostafa Ayaz but in this case, the Laplace transform of the forcing function, F(t), must also be included.